# How to connect the c# script with ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET. I designed a simple UI website using ASP.NET and wrote scripts in c#. Now i want to connect the script with the ASP.NET website such that when i click the button in the ASP.NET website, it executes the c# script. Sorry, this is a silly question but i can't move forward without having the idea how to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your ASP.NET site using C# in the code behind the page?

Comment: Yes Shane, it is using c# in the code behind the page? But i wanted to connect the button from the website to the different large script in c#.

Comment: I would suggest you invest some time on reading any basic .net book and then continue with your website. Many of them have simple examples. Otherwise you will be stuck on every other step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kaps, i already have the website with Good UI. I'm just having trouble connecting with the c# selenium script that i have in my VB.net project folder.

Comment: Can you give a code example of your c# script so we have a better idea of what you are trying to do. Otherwise, the answers everyone has provided should work for you. You just put the C# code from your script in the event handler for the button in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply attach to the event on the button (in this example click):

```
 <asp:Button ID="someButton" runat="server" Click="someButton_Click" Text="Click Me!" />
```

And then in your code behind:

```
 // your ASPX code behind
 protected void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Executes this code. 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tejs but i wanted the button to execute the different script which is written in c#-selenium. Is there anyway i can call the function from different script written in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Your ASPX pages should have code-behind files already associated with them. If you wrote your code in separate C# files, I would suggest pasting the code into the provided code-behind file. You may need to manipulate the designer.cs file too, to assign the events to the appropriate handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right, but even easier (especially if you are a beginner) is to right click on your c# page (.cs page), click on "View Designer" in the context menu, click on the source tab at the bottom, add the button and then double click on it and it will automatically add a handler. This makes sure you get the syntax of the handler right.